# What are some recommended learning resources for OpenSSL and cryptography?

Tags: ssl, cryptography, openssl

I need go dig in and finally learn how to use OpenSSL via command line and in addition to that I would like to get a solid foundation on general cryptography.

Google searches so far have not been too helpful. I tend to like to find a few GOOD books and then watch some lectures/talks about a subject so I can really dive into what I'm learning so I can actually grasp all the new vernacular.

So far I bought "Network Security with OpenSSL" and I'm reading it but I have to admin some of the stuff is going over my head.

If your an openssl guru, what helped you get to that level?!? :D

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: PS: Please help yourself by posting your question at http://security.stackexchange.com/faq. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in addition to that I would like to get a solid foundation on general cryptography.

It's getting a bit old but the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) is one of the **best**, complete, deep but not impossible to understand, resource available in a book (with pdf available, but see license for using them).

Answer (score 1):

First, understand that openssl is an implementation of algorithms and protocols; but if you don't have at least a basic understanding of the what the algorithms and protocols do (have read the wikipedia pages at a minimum), you cannot understand the implementation.

Once you've reached the point where you know what you want to do, but need to learn how to do it within openssl, then I suggest:

1. See if 'Network Security with OpenSSL' describes how to do it.
2. Check the man pages
3. Grep the source